# How to best preserve state in newly installed mobile app (iOs and Android) - Deferred Deep Linking

Tags: android, ios, mobile, deep-linking

We're developing a mobile app where we need to gracefully handle invitation links to join a team with just a URL. We're researching the best way to do this in both iOS and Android and there seems to be a lot of different solutions over the years, to the point that it's worth asking the community and updating the general knowledge on this topic.

- Using native "Deferred Deep Linking" to pass information to the newly installed app

  - Clipboard approach to pass data from link --> newly opened app (brittle if something is copied between original link usage and opening the app)
  - Cookie within browser which is checked after installation - deprecated because of security
  - Pass URL parameters to the app stores - doable in Google Play Store natively, Apple does not allow unique data (privacy, App Tracking Transparency [ATT], etc)
- Using third party services like Branch.io, AppsFlyer.com, Firebase Dynamic Links - most

Seems like the most sensible approach would be to use Google Play Native capability + a robust implementation in iOS where you 1) pass a URL parameter to the Apple App Store letting the newly installed app know that there's an invitation in progress, 2) use the Clipboard approach to pass data, 3) if data is not available, but URL parameter for installation present --> prompt user to open the browser to continue invite process (deep link at that point).

How are you doing this or would do this if you had to enable this kind of functionality?